# Cannot scroll to see full element because of fixed footer

Tags: css, frontend

I got the following structure:

```
<header></header>
<main>
<card />
</main>
<footer></footer>

header {
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1100;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}


main {
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

card {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 25px;
}

footer {
    top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The card actually is a login form with two inputs and has to be in the center of the screen. I used the main to wrap and center it. But now the problem is that on horizontal orientation and when the height is reduced to some pxs it is not possible to see the whole card. Part of it is covered by the footer. Any idea how I can center it and scrolling to be possible.

Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-meitner-ocgz9

Answer (score 0):

add this to you'r body maybe youre problem solve

```
 body {
   min-height:100vh;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you place it to a code pen, would be easier to help you.

I can only assume that if you change main to the below it might help:

```
main {
  height: calc(100vh - 130px);
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

Also check you have body { margin: 0 }. As browsers adds margin automatically, so your 100% layout does have extra height.

Comment: in login.js try changing:                                                                                         
`const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paperContainer: {
    display: "grid",
    placeItems: "center",
    height: "auto",
    paddingBottom: "60px"
  }, `  Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

from the main container remove the height and add `margin-bottom` equals to the height of the footer.

```
paperContainer: {
  display: "grid",
  placeItems: "center",
  marginBottom:'60px'
}
```

And to avoid some styling issues regarding height, add `min-height` if required.
[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-tdd-dzbk0)

Answer (score 0):

**Got a very simple solution!!**

```
paper: {
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    padding: "40px 25px",
    paddingBottom: "100px"
  },
```

just give the paddingBottom to the paper, you can also use it conditionally if the user is using mobile and the width of the view > height of the view. It looks fine without that too.

Check this out!!
[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-thunder-dy5l8?file=/src/Login.js:328-438)

let me know if you still have an issue.